# Find number with least number of signifcant bits in an interval

Tags: python, bit-manipulation, intervals

Given a lower and upper bound, what is the number within these boundaries with the minimal number of significant bits?
The number of significant bits is the difference of the position of most and least significant bit (MSB - LSB).

Examples:

```
def sig_bits(x: int) -> int:
    """Count the span of significant bits in an integer."""
    assert 0 < x < 2**64
    as_str = "{:064b}".format(x)
    msb, lsb = as_str.index("1"), len(as_str) - as_str.rindex("1") - 1
    return msb - lsb + 1

def min_sig(a: int, b: int) -> int:
    assert a <= b
    return min((sig_bits(i), i) for i in range(a, b+1))[1]
        
min_sig(5, 10) = 8  # only 1 significant bit: bit 4
min_sig(5, 7) = 6  # bits 2 and 3 are significant
```

Is there a more efficient way?

Comment: Just the beginning of an idea, but wouldn't the winner be the one that is divisible by the highest power of 2? And btw, in the range 2 to 8 for example, 2, 4, and 8 all have only 1 significant digit. Who wins then?

Comment: This implementation of `sig_bits` is odd, for example `sig_bits(1) = 64` surely that's not what you meant?

Comment: @harold you are right, it's odd. I just wanted to provide an naive implementation to give an idea and haven't tested.

Comment: You're using the terms "LSB" and "MSB" in a non-standard way, which is confusing. The LSB of an integer is always in position 0. It would be clearer if you referred to LSSB or LS1B (least-significant *set* bit) and MSSB or MS1B (most-significant *set* bit).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on my comment, I'll propose this solution. I simply calculate the highest power of 2 inferior or equal to the length of the range (let's name it H); then there are 1 or 2 numbers in the range divisible by H; if there are 2, I get the one that is divisible by 2H:

```
def min_sig_swifty(a: int, b:int) -> int:
    highest_guaranteed_power_of_2_divisor = 2 ** (int.bit_length(b - a + 1) - 1)
    smallest_factor_in_range = (a - 1) // highest_guaranteed_power_of_2_divisor + 1
    if not smallest_factor_in_range % 2:
        return smallest_factor_in_range * highest_guaranteed_power_of_2_divisor
    else:
        highest_factor_in_range = b // highest_guaranteed_power_of_2_divisor
        return highest_factor_in_range * highest_guaranteed_power_of_2_divisor
```

Note: thanks to Kelly Bundy for pointing out a rounding problem with log2, and to harold for a great suggestion (using int.bit_length).

Edit: here's a better version using bit shifting instead of multiplications and divisions by powers of 2 (thanks again to Kelly Bundy):

```
def min_sig_swifty(a: int, b:int) -> int:
    highest_guaranteed_power_of_2_exponent = int.bit_length(b - a + 1) - 1
    smallest_factor_in_range = ((a - 1) >> highest_guaranteed_power_of_2_exponent) + 1
    if not smallest_factor_in_range % 2:
        return smallest_factor_in_range << highest_guaranteed_power_of_2_exponent
    else:
        highest_factor_in_range = b >> highest_guaranteed_power_of_2_exponent
        return highest_factor_in_range << highest_guaranteed_power_of_2_exponent
```

Comment: Just avoid `log2` altogether, there are more appropriate integer functions that are always accurate

Comment: Which would you recommend? Indeed I should have been wary of using floats! In the meantime I'll just add the check/fix

Comment: `bit_length` could probably do this

Comment: If the numbers are huge (think thousands of bits or more), then I think if b has n bits, this is O(n^2) due to the division. Perhaps better, not sure what division complexity really is. But you could easily make it O(n) by dropping the `2 **` and shifting instead of dividing/multiplying.

Comment: You're right (even though in this case the numbers are topped at 2 ** 64); I'll at least remove the part of my answer about complexity, where I forgot to take into account the intrinsic complexity of operations. I'm not used to bit shifting, so I'll need to do some self-training before updating my answer.

Answer (score 2):

```
def min_sig(a: int, b: int) -> int:
    while a <= b:
        result = a
        a += a & -a
    return result
```

`a` has some prefix, then its last 1, then zeros. Changing those zeros to anything else would make it worse:

```
a   = ?????100000
a+1 = ?????100001
a+2 = ?????100010
           .
           .
           .
      ?????111111
```

The next larger number that has any chance of being better than `a` is the number we get by adding `a`'s last 1-bit to it.

That lengthens the suffix of zeros, so we do at most log2(b) steps.